# Marking file as executable on OSX using C (Carbon, standard C/C++)

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

I'm looking for a way to programatically set the 'executable' bit on a file on OS X. I don't want to invoke 'chmod a+x' but I want the same effect as the chmod call. Any suggestions? A carbon API or any other C/C++ function would work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See chmod(2), e.g. http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/chmod/osx-10.4.php (I think it's unchanged in 10.5).

Comment: Since it's standard POSIX, they aren't going to change it any time soon.

Comment: Likely not, but, you know Apple -- they might always have some nifty (backwards-compatible) extension up their sleeve;-).

Answer (score 1):

There is a "chmod" C library call.  Go to a terminal window and type "man 2 chmod".